# Java 8: Collector groupby with list nested class

Tags: java, grouping, collectors, collect

I am trying to get following Map via Java 8

```
Class One {
    String one;
    List <Two> two;
}

Class Two {
    BigDecimal bd;
}
```

How do I collect a Map which contains grouping by One.one i.e., first parameter of map. For second parameter of map sum of Two.bd.

Comment: Can you clarify?

Comment: You need to explain in a lot more detail what you want.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this:

```
List<One> list = ...;

Map<String, BigDecimal> result1 = list.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(One::getOne, // key is One.one
        Collectors.mapping(one -> one.getTwo().stream() // get stream of One.two
            .map(Two::getBd) // map to Bd
            .reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add), // reduce to sum
            Collectors.reducing(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add) // sum sums
        )
    ));
```

This will sum all the `bd` of `Two`, and then also sum the sums for `One`s that have the same `one`.

---

Although things would be simpler if Java8 had a flatMapping collector, one has been added to [Java9](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8071600):

```
public static <T, U, A, R>
Collector<T, ?, R> flatMapping(Function<? super T, ? extends Stream<? extends U>> mapper,
                               Collector<? super U, A, R> downstream) {
    BiConsumer<A, ? super U> downstreamAccumulator = downstream.accumulator();
    return Collector.of(downstream.supplier(),
                        (r, t) -> mapper.apply(t).sequential().forEach(u -> downstreamAccumulator.accept(r, u)),
                        downstream.combiner(),
                        downstream.finisher(),
                        downstream.characteristics().stream().toArray(Collector.Characteristics[]::new));
}
```

Which would make:

```
Map<String, BigDecimal> result1 = list.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(One::getOne,
        flatMapping(one -> one.getTwo().stream().map(Two::getBd),
            Collectors.reducing(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add)
        )
    ));
```

Comment: Actually, your variant throws an exception whenever it encounters a duplicate value for `One::getOne`. Correct collector here **is** grouping by with a correct downstream collector, not a `toMap`.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov We seem to understand the question differently. I take from the statement that the sum of `bd` should be the second parameter of the map that this is the wanted solution. But I've added another solution for your interpretation.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov it gives exception - Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Duplicate key 8.002
 at java.util.stream.Collectors.lambda$throwingMerger$114(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.HashMap.merge(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.stream.Collectors.lambda$toMap$172(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$3ReducingSink.accept(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(Unknown Source)

Comment: @JornVernee Ups, missed your edit when I posted my answer. The first part of your answer is wrong. You can do it with groupingBy (as in the second part of your answer), or you could also do it by correctly handling the collisions of `One::getOne` with one of the overloaded versions of `Collectors.toMap`.

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner I misunderstood the intention behind the question, thanks for the feedback. I have already deleted the wrong version.

Comment: @JornVernee I've left the first part of my answer (which is exactly as yours), but now I've also added another approach with `Collectors.toMap`

Answer (score 2):

This will do what you want:

```
Map<String, BigDecimal> map = ones.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        One::getOne,
        Collectors.mapping(
            one -> one.getTwo().stream()
                .map(Two::getBd)
                .reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add),
            Collectors.reducing(
                BigDecimal.ZERO,
                BigDecimal::add))));
```

This collects by `One.one`, transforming each `One.two` to a `BigDecimal` that is the sum of its `Two.bd` attributes, then it reduces and sums again in case there are repeated `One.one` in the list.

**EDIT:**

First part of @Jorn Vernee's edited answer is exactly the same as my own's, so here I present another approach:

```
Map<String, BigDecimal> map = ones.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        One::getOne,
        one -> one.getTwo().stream()
            .map(Two::getBd)
            .reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add),
        BigDecimal::add));
```

Here I'm using the overloaded version of `Collectors.toMap`, which takes care of collisions by using the supplied merge function (in this case `BigDecimal::add`).

Comment: I still prefer `groupingBy` a little more, because it displays intent better than `toMap`. But nice idea in your second snippet.